# Access perl module within Bash script

Tags: perl, bash

I have a perl module with data definitions (hashes, arrays, etc.), is there any way I can access that data from inside a bash script?  This isn't working for me...

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -e 'use Data'
tests=`perl -e "@tests"; `
echo "Perl tests = ${tests}"         # prints "Perl tests = "
```

The module looks something like this:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( @tests );
our @tests = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have package variable `@tests` inside `Data` module,

```
perl -MData -e 'print "$_\n" for @Data::tests'
```

For perl 5.10 and above,

```
perl -MData -E 'say for @Data::tests'
```

Comment: `perl -MData -le'print for @Data::tests'`

Comment: `perl -MData -E'say for @Data::tests'`  (5.10+)

Comment: This works great thank you, is there a way I can access a hash in the Data module?

Comment: @user3487205 how should hash look like, ie. `perl -MData -E 'say "$_:$tests{$_}" for keys %Data::tests'` for `key1:val1\nkey2:val2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module from the command line with -M

```
perl -MData -e'print map {"$_\n"} @tests;'
```

In the code you give, you run one interpreter that loads Data. It exits. You then run a second interpreter, which prints @tests. As that's the only action the second interpreter has performed, it's uninitialized, and prints nothing.